# How to write a parallel safe random number generator in Fortran

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran

This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60075931/2853667) question.

I find that `Random_number()` is not reliable for parallel programming, it gives non reproducible results, and my program heavily relies on random numbers.

How can I write a random number generator in Fortran that is parallel safe?

Or where can I find it?

Comment: Rather than engage in some tricky coding (which you don't know how to do yet) first convince yourself that you **must** take that approach.  Don't reject out of hand the approach of using a sequential PRNG to generate all the random numbers you need and putting them somewhere (perhaps in a shared memory array) your separate processes/threads can read their own chunks.  Reject this only after you have programmed it up and determined that it is a bottleneck in performance.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark How do I tell the compiler to divide the array of random numbers in chunks and give one to each thread?

Comment: A lot of information is missing here.  What compiler and operating system?  How are you seeding the PRNG?  Are you certain that the non-reproducible results you observe are not a manifestation of a problem with with code?

Comment: If you are programming shared memory you get the master thread to populate an array of `n*10^m` random numbers, where `n` is the number of threads you are using and `m` is a value appropriate to your calculation, then as the computation proceeds each of the `n` threads reads from its own chunk of the shared array.

Comment: If you are using gfortran, the manual tells you how to use random_number with multiple threads: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html.   Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158213/thread-safe-mersenne-twister

Answer (score 2):

Since Fortran 2018 it is possible to initialise the pseudo-random number generator of the invoking image so that the pseudo-random number sequence will differ from that of other images that execute a similar statement, and will be different on subsequent execution of the program.

```
CALL RANDOM_INIT (REPEATABLE=.FALSE., IMAGE_DISTINCT=.TRUE.)
```

More info in the [Fortran 2018 Standard, Section 16.9.155](https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/18/18-007r1.pdf)

Comment: While true, I think a multiple-image program is probably well beyond the level of experience of the person asking this question, compared with a threading model like OpenMP.